# VS code doesn't detect JSX errors

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I started React project and all works fine, but my VS code doesn't detect any errors.

There is a special extension for that? It shouldn't have been built in feature?

Comment: Are you using some react extension?

Comment: No, I've three extensions none of them related to react

Comment: You should setup linting system something like [this](https://blog.echobind.com/integrating-prettier-eslint-airbnb-style-guide-in-vscode-47f07b5d7d6a)